# How can I trigger a Jenkins Job ONLY when opening a GitLab Merge request and how to trigger ONLY when merging it

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We do use GitLab Plugin for Jenkins.
I want to trigger two jobs in Jenkins:

1. Valiation (includes a build command with a --test-only tag)
2. Deployment (actual build onto target system)

The first jenkins job should only be triggered when I open a merge request (or push new changes to its respective branch) using the GitLab extension option under "Build Triggery > Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL: xyz (<- webhook is set up correclty): check; Push Events check; Opened Merge Request: check).
However it will already be triggered when I create a new branch in Gitlab itself or if I push a new branch from my local via e.g. Sourcetree. However at this point it shouldn't. But only when actually crteating a merge request using this branch.

The second jenkins job mentioned, I reckon there is no real option using the GitLab Plugin straight forward, as it does not give me a "Build Trigger" option called something like "merge request merge events".
Also I assume such option would be under the "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab" option, and this would lead again to the issue having with the first validation job.

Is there a way to only trigger when a Gitlab merge request is created (plus push, and comments, etc. if needed) and to trigger the build job when the merge request is merged (afaik there is an option to do so using bitbucket plugin in jenkins, where it is called pull request)?

We already set up working webhooks between gitlab and jenkins.
However the build trigger will be triggered too early.